# 'Server Connection Error' on GCP (AI Platform Notebook)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, jupyter-lab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, google-dl-platform

I am facing some issues with GCP and the AI Platform (Jupyterlab)
It seems that I am unable to maintain a stable connection with the server for a long time. I keep getting those '**server connection error**' message. From there two possibilities:

- either nothing happens and my cell keeps running
  or
- the cells have stopped running and I can see the status '**No Kernel!**' on the top right of the notebook. Whenever I select a kernel (python 3) again, depending on my luck I can either keep working, or the cell will display the running status (with the * on the left of it) but the kernel status on the bottom left will stay on : 'connected' (instead of 'busy'). For the latter, I need to restart the kernel and run all the cells again, which can be very long.

Sometimes this happens as soon as I run the first cell after (re)starting the instance, sometimes a bit later. The longest stable period I was able to work on the notebook without any issue was 20, 30-ish minutes, which is quite annoying.

Configuration of my main instance : 
 - 16 CPUs 
 - 60gb of RAM 
 - A P100 NVIDIA GPU

I have tried different types of instance and I keep having the same problem, network at home is stable.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqXZa.png)

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

What operating system and browser are you using at work?
I had the same problem as you did on Ubuntu 18 with the Firefox browser. 
When I switched to Windows with Chrome the error did not reoccur, even though it was the same network.

Comment: Switching from Firefox to Chrome on Mac eliminated  'Server Connection Errors' for me as well.

Comment: I frequently receive this error when using Windows with Chrome, and with an instance whose disk has plenty of room. @gogasca Any other insights?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue today: according to the [google docs](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/troubleshooting?hl=nl#opening_a_notebook_results_in_a_598_network_read_timeout_error) the cause for this is that the docker/ Jupyter service is not starting.

The cause why these services couldn't be started in our specific case was a full disk.