# Jupyter Notebook on Google Cloud: Server Connection Error after around 20 hours

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I was running a jupyter notebook on the google cloud platform for around 20 hours when I received the following error. More specifically, a notebook instance on the AI Platform.
It happened within the second epoch at batch 52500 out of 292893.

[image]

The notebook was not able to reconnect, so I would need to run everything again. I initially thought that it used up all RAM or disk but doesn't seem like it:

[image]

I did not close the browser tab at any time. I did not shut down the notebook instance at any time. Using us-west1-b for the instance.

Any idea how to not make this happen again?

Comment: Could it be an internet issue on your side ? Because according to the error it looks like it or some issue with your browser, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423090/server-connection-error-on-gcp-ai-platform-notebook). Which browser were you using ?

Comment: I am using chromium. I haven't noticed any internet issues. The connection is usually stable but ofc could be that something happened in the middle of the night

Comment: I decided to run it again but this time I will separately run an internet connection logger, so I can see whether internet issue is a possibility. Fingers crossed it will work :')